# Retrieving Java list from ruby

Tags: java, ruby, list

My service(written in Java) returns me an output in the format:

```
 "serviceMetricList": 
  [
    {"MetricDataList": 
      {"metricDataList": 
        [
          {"metricDate": "2011-04-05T14:50:00.000Z", 
           "metricValue": "427448.0"}, 
          {"metricDate": "2011-04-12T14:30:00.000Z", 
           "metricValue": "430089.0"}
        ]
      }, 
     "urlSerialNo": "1"}
     }
  ]
```

I need to retrieve the values metricDate and metricValue from my Ruby client. Am not sure about how this can be done. Any help in this regard will be great.

Comment: This looks like a very strange data format. Why are there more closing braces than opening ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to parse this data format, you first need to know what data format it is. It doesn't appear to be any well-known data format and it's not any format I know. It's obviously not JSON, nor is it YAML and definitely not XML.

So, you'll probably have to write your own parser. Or a preprocessor which converts the data into a more well-known format, for wich a parser already exists.

For example, if you were to convert the example to YAML, it would look something like this:

```
"serviceMetricList": 
  [
    {"MetricDataList": 
      {"metricDataList": 
        [
          {"metricDate": "2011-04-05T14:50:00.000Z", 
           "metricValue": "427448.0"}, 
          {"metricDate": "2011-04-12T14:30:00.000Z", 
           "metricValue": "430089.0"}
        ]
      }, 
     "urlSerialNo": "1"
    }
  ]
```

And you could parse it like this:

```
require 'yaml'
h = YAML.load(your_java_data)

Date.parse(h['serviceMetricList'][0]['MetricDataList']['metricDataList'][0]['metricDate'])
# => #<Date: 2011-04-05 (4911313/2,0,2299161)>

Float(h['serviceMetricList'][0]['MetricDataList']['metricDataList'][0]['metricValue'])
# => 427448.0

# or maybe, if you don't like to lose precision:
require 'bigdecimal'

BigDecimal(h['serviceMetricList'][0]['MetricDataList']['metricDataList'][0]['metricValue'])
# => #<BigDecimal:eb8240,'0.427448E6',8(12)>
```

Comment: Thank you. Those were objects I had declared. But could be accessed in a way simiar to what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you java service spits JSON (looks close to [this](http://json.org/example.html), no ?)

You can try and parse that with a [JSON Parser in ruby](http://flori.github.com/json/):

```
require 'rubygems'; require 'json';
a = JSON.parse( "{"+ str + "}" )
```

Btw, your sample is broken, the } is closed twice after *urlSerialNo*. Apart from that, it's JSON !